# ggplot not ploting histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a mirrored histogram based on the following data (snippet):

[image]

Where on the x-axis x goes from 0 to 150 (range of both variables Ilhavo and VNTelha-Maia) in subgroups of 10 and on the "dual" y-axis is the number of times (horas) each number under Ilhavo and VNTelha-Maia are repeated.

Basically I want to get something like this:
[image]

However, no matter what I do I can't seem to create it.

Here's what I have tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)

p <- ggplot(QualidadeARO3, aes(x=Ilhavo) ) +
  geom_histogram( breaks=seq(0, 150, by=10), aes(x = Ilhavo , y = ..horas..), fill="#69b3a2" ) +
  geom_label( aes(x=Ilhavo, y=horas, label="Ilhavo"), color="#69b3a2") +
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 150, by=10), aes(x = VNTelha-Maia, y = -..horas..), fill= "#404080") +
  geom_label( aes(x=VNTelha-Maia, y=horas, label="VN Telha"), color="#404080") +
 
  xlab("microgramas/metro cúbico")
```

But nothing happens. Any help?

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x) ) +
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 150, by=10), aes(x = Ilhavo, y = ..density..), fill="#69b3a2" ) +
  geom_label( aes(x=100, y=0.05, label="Ilhavo"), color="#69b3a2") +
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 150, by=10), aes(x = VNTelha_Maia, y = -..density..), fill= "#404080") +
  geom_label( aes(x=100, y=-0.05, label="VNTelha_Maia"), color="#404080") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]